# Get A Name in URL Using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, anchor

I want to get the URL using (preferably) PHP or JavaScript. The page was opened using an anchor name (e.g. `index.php#aboutme`). When I use

```
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$script = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
$params = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

it returns `http://afterimagedesign.tk/index.php` without the `#home` on the end. How can I get this?

Comment: `window.location.hash` in JS wil return `#home`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP cannot ever get this hashtag (that's what it's called), because the browser never sends it to the server in any form.

JavaScript can access it with `window.location.hash`, but that's **client-side**.

**[What are the difference between server-side and client-side programming?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-difference-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming)**

Comment: It is called a [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). A hashtag is a way of marking a word on twitter as something to be searched for.

Comment: He says 'the page was opened using an anchor name' so I guess there is a request including the hash to the server.

Comment: @Quentin: Hashtags are words or phrases prefixed with the symbol #, a form of metadata tag. (From Wikipedia), but sure.

Comment: @J.H.: That doesn't mean anything. It might as well mean that the normal page was requested, and then the fragment identifier was used to AJAX some more content into the site.

Comment: @J.H. — No, the fragment identifier is handled entirely client side. It is never sent to the server. It represents part of the resource, the client fetches the whole resource when scrolls to the given part.

Comment: This worked perfectly when I set `var anchor = window.location.hash;`. I have 5 dives exactly the same size all on top over each other and only set one as visible. I used this to choose which one is visible on load so if people link to my site or enter the URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
echo parse_url("http://localhost/index.php#aboutme",PHP_URL_FRAGMENT);
?>
```

Output: aboutme

or with JS

```
window.location.hash
```

Comment: I think the point is to find it for the URL which accessed it?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to access this data with PHP would be to send it to PHP via an AJAX call when the page loads. As the other responses have said, the hashtag is never sent to PHP inside the original request. So you would have to send it afterwards.

If this is information you need, you would have to change your application to not use hashtags and instead append this data to the query string (ie index.php?home rather then index.php#home and manually scroll the page using javascript when it loads based on this.